# 2-D Array - Expression must have a constant value error

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I'm attempting the [Latin Square Daily Challenge on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/6v29zk/170821_challenge_328_easy_latin_squares/) and I wanted to use an array which allocates size during run-time by using the following code:

```
int n;
cout << "Please enter the size of the Latin Square: ";
cin >> n;
int latinsquare[n][n];
```

This works in online compilers but not in Visual Studio 17. Is there a way to do this in the Microsoft C++ compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because variable-length arrays are non-standard in C++ ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/335858)). You can allocate `latinsquare` using `new`, but an idiomatic way of doing it in C++ is to use a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> latinsquare(n, std::vector<int>(n, 0));
```

Comment: That was insightful cheers! It works as intended but why is this '0' instead of 'n' in this piece of code `latinsquare(n, std::vector<int>(n, 0))`? Also, may sound a little silly but how would I output both arrays within that vector? Thanks

Comment: @LiamJM Zero is the value being assigned to each element of the vector as part of its initialization. Outputting the arrays would take two nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

[VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is not a part of [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) standard. If you want to use them you need compiler extension.

But you may

- Create it dynamically via `new` and `delete` operators
- Use `std::vector`

Comment: `std::array` wouldn't work, because they require fixed size at compile-time.